# PyQt5: QLabel.text() function causes app to crash

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm new to PyQt5. I'm currently working on a calculator just for some practice, but for some reason, the app crashes when I use the `eval()` function in the `QLabel().setText()` function.

Here's a sample snippet:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtw
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = qtw.QWidget()
        self.win.setLayout(qtw.QVBoxLayout())

        self.label = qtw.QLabel("2+3")
        self.label.setFont(qtg.QFont("consolas", 16))
        self.win.layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.btn = qtw.QPushButton("Click Me", clicked=self.pressed)
        self.win.layout().addWidget(self.btn)

        self.win.show()

    def pressed(self):
        # self.label.setText("Hello World 123") #  Does not crash
        # print(self.label.text()) #  Does not crash
        self.label.setText(eval(self.label.text())) # Crashes

app = qtw.QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Here, the app crashes when I use `self.label.setText(eval(self.label.text()))`. The crash does not happen when I use `.setText()` or `.text()` separately (as shown in the snippet), so I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with either of the methods. I'm not able to understand why the app crashes just for using the `eval()` function.

Is there any solution to this problem? It would be great if anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

**OS: Windows 11,
Python Version: 3.10.5**

Comment: The real question is: why do you want to use `eval` (which is generally discouraged and should only be used with *extreme* care only when you *actually* know what you're doing)?

Comment: @musicamante: Oh! I didn't know. Is there any other way to evaluate a numerical expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `eval` evaluates your expression, that is '2+3', it returns the result of the expression, exactly as it happens in an ordinary interpreted line

```
>>> 2+3
5
```

But, all the above elements are `int`, including the result being printed, while QLabel `setText` requires a string. Thus

```
self.label.setText(str(eval(self.label.text())))
```

`str` could be indifferently into the `eval` expression, in that case the result of `eval` would be of string type.

In any case, keep in mind what @musicamante has commented: whenever possibile, avoid `eval` and use a custom parser

Comment: Ah! Can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Next time, please, report the exception encountered: it would have been much easier to infer the issue!

Comment: The thing is there WAS no exception. I click the button, the app loads for 2 seconds, and closes with `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`. If there was an error, I definitely would've reported that. Thanks.

Comment: Wow very weird. I got the TypeError exception and this let me understand straightforwardly the cause.

Comment: @Lenovo360 Whether you're using an IDE (which not always is able to show the full traceback) or trying to run the script by double clicking it, always try to *also* run it from a terminal or prompt. If you do that with your original script, you will certainly see what caused the error.

Comment: @musicamante: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. The traceback shows up when I run it with a terminal. Is there any reason why the traceback doesn't show up when you run it directly from the IDE? I'm using the same interpreter in all places (IDE and Terminal).

Comment: It may depend on how the IDE works and how its configured (including its debugging). Also, sometimes the IDE might not be able to catch debug warnings/messages that are directly created by Qt. In any case, you should *always* try the program outside of the IDE, even if it doesn't have any problem, as the IDE might use a specific configuration or environment that could make the program behave differently.